# Prevent showing hidden files and folder to gallery in android

Tags: android, filesystems

I am creating an project for hiding files and folder.I am able to hide folder and file from file system with below code,but it show on gallery.is their any way to prevent file and folder to showing in gallery.

My code for hiding any file is:

```
public static void hideFile(File file){
    File dstFile = new File(file.getParent(), "." + file.getName());
    file.renameTo(dstFile);
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: don't refresh gallery thats the solution....Enjoy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Gallary app is meant to show all image/media files, you can skip it accesing your files by creating `.nomedia` folder.

Next, place all your files, that you are planning to hide, in this folder.

`.nomedia` is a  hint to Gallery (and other similar apps) there is no media accessible in the folder to show.

One more related point is that If the folder already contains some images before adding '.nomedia' file, the gallery will not hide those images.

Comment: how to achieve this? Can you give me example code for this?

Comment: simple java folder `File dir = new File(".nomedia");
dir.mkdir();` and then add all your files that you want to hide into this!

Comment: `String dirPath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + ".nomedia";
File projDir = new File(dirPath);
if (!projDir.exists())
    projDir.mkdirs();` This will create a `.nomedia` folder inside `/data/data/your.app/files`